# How to create menu items both in google doc & sheet from single apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create menu for both doc and sheet from single script OnOpen(), but its not showing on both doc and sheet.

```
function onOpen() 
{ if (DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()) { DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom Menu') 
.addItem('Document Item 1', 'documentFunction1'); 
.addItem('Document Item 2', 'documentFunction2'); 
.addToUi(); }

if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()) { SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom Menu') 
.addItem('sheet Item 1', 'sheetFunction1'); 
.addItem('sheet Item 2', 'sheetFunction2'); 
.addToUi(); }
}
```

without if condition, it shows menu only for document, not on sheet.

single script should show menus in both doc and sheet

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `single script should show menus in both doc and sheet`. I think that `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` and `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` cannot be used to one of Documents and Spreadsheets, simultaneously. So, in this case, first, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: i want to create menu on both doc and sheet from my apps script project

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from `i want to create menu on both doc and sheet from my apps script project `, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: By the way, in your showing script, `;` of `.addItem('Document Item 1', 'documentFunction1');`, `.addItem('Document Item 2', 'documentFunction2');`, `.addItem('sheet Item 1', 'sheetFunction1');` and `.addItem('sheet Item 2', 'sheetFunction2');` is not required. But, if you are actually using your showing script, I guess that when the script is saved, an error like SyntaxError occurs. So, I guessed that this m ight not be related to your current situation and your goal.

Comment: I am not getting any error, 
If i use any one of below code, its showing menu on doc or sheet
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom Menu') 
.addItem('Document Item 1', 'documentFunction1'); 
.addItem('Document Item 2', 'documentFunction2'); 
.addToUi();

Or

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom Menu') 
.addItem('sheet Item 1', 'sheetFunction1'); 
.addItem('sheet Item 2', 'sheetFunction2'); 
.addToUi();

Comment: but if i try to use both codes in onopen(), its not showing menu on sheet, its works for first .getUi() code

So I am trying to use if condition, i.e. "if (DocumentApp.getActiveDocument())" but its getting hide on doc also

Comment: I guess my question is why?  `onOpen()` in code.gs is bound to either a spreadsheet or a document.  What good are any document function in a spreadsheet project?  I could understand if you had a script project library that is being shared by spreadsheets and documents.